# Spring load time weaving with aspectj issue

Tags: spring, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I am trying to use aspectj with spring's load time weaving capabilities. I am following the guidelines described here at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments

I have completed the configuration inside a spring mvc application running in tomcat. I have also provided -javaagent argument to JVM in eclipse. 
When i launch application the InstrumentationSavingAgent.premain() is called to set the 'instrumentation' reference which will be used by spring for load time weaving. But when spring later calls getInstrumentation() the 'instrumentation' reference is found to be NULL.
How can I make sure that spring uses the same InstrumentationSavingAgent class instance while setting as well as getting the 'instrumentation' reference.

Comment: It is unlikely for you to get an answer to question in it's current form. I recommend you create a [mcve].